# getting an error message when I run python pd.read_csv code

Tags: python, pandas

**When I try run this code to read a CSV file that is located in my C drive:**

```py
import pandas as pd


fd_inspections = pd.read_csv('c:\food_inspections.csv')
```

**I get this error**

```py
runfile('C:/food_inspections.py', wdir='C:')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-369bc957a5c4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/food_inspections.py', wdir='C:')

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/food_inspections.py", line 13, in <module>
    fd_inspections =pd.read_csv('c:\food_inspections.csv')

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 405, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 764, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 985, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1605, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 394, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:4209)

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 710, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:8873)

FileNotFoundError: File b'c:\x0cood_inspections.csv' does not exist
```

**Why is it trying to read in a different filename that isnt't in the code?**

Comment: Be careful using backslashes in paths. They are also escape characters. Try instead: `fd_inspections = pd.read_csv('c:/food_inspections.csv')`

Answer (score 2):

- just put `r''` before your path to file. Because `\` escapes character.
- Another way is to use `\\` in your string to escape that `\`.

```py
import pandas as pd
fd_inspections = pd.read_csv(r'c:\food_inspections.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to print out the filepath.

```py
print('c:\food_inspections.csv')
```

It returns the following:

```py
c:\x0cood_inspections.csv
```

This happens because there is a \f in your string, which has a special meaning. Try with raw string:

```py
fd_inspections = pd.read_csv(r'c:\food_inspections.csv')
```

This should work.